# Como posso melhorar a minha pergunta?

Tags: suporte

Criei uma pergunta que foi mal aceita pela comunidade. Ela surgiu a partir de um problema que não consegui solucionar. Ela obteve uma resposta que acabou solucionando o meu problema. Porém gostaria de melhorar essa minha [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/403833/problemas-ao-converter-variavel-javascript-para-transferir-em-uma-rota-do-larave) e tirar os 2 pontos negativos dela. Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Essa pergunta é duplicada. Você precisa na sua pergunta ter um bom português, evita palavras repetidas e não ter muito informalidade(amigo,querido,gostoso e por favorzinho)

Comment: @MauryDeveloper isso não tem nada a ver com ela ser uma duplicata.

Comment: é uma duplicada. Você não que não viu o título das perguntas. Ter uma pergunta de boa qualidade é mesma coisa de melhorar uma pergunta.